# Angular getting variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and I have problem with data binding.
When I try to get value from `$scope.mytext` i get `{{mytext}}`. Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="myApp">
      <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
    <script>
        var MainController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.mytext = "Angular JS Rulez";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app> 
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <p>{{mytext}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Please make a better effort to format your code properly (including correct indentation).

Comment: @Knight did you try the code below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some errors in the way you set up the app.

You never defined the app, you have declared `ng-app` twice, the second time you haven't assigned anything to `ng-app` and there was an error with the CDN you referenced. Once you defined the app, you then needed to assign the controller to this app.

The below code will work for you, and you can also see the code working by checking out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1341/) demo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
     <title>Hello</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

     <script> 
          var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
          myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
               $scope.mytext = "Angular JS Rulez";;
          }]);
     </script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <p>{{mytext}}</p>
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're calling the app in the html, but you haven't defined it anywhere. You must:

1. define 'myApp' in the javascript portion, and then
2. assign the controller on it.

Your code simply calls MainController which isn't defined properly on any app.

A basic setup in this case is, as Paul mentions:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller(MyAppController, ['$scope', function($scope) {
   ...add $scope elements here ... 
]);
```

Also you shouldn't need to call ng-app twice in the html.